# How to style Grid cell/row background without using classname generator

Tags: formatting, vaadin, cell, vaadin-grid

I searched a lot, but every solution was to include some constant CSS class names into the page, and use the Column's ClassNameGenerator to set the proper classname on the cell/row.

Now this might be a good solution when the developer can decide on formatting a cell, however when a user can decide (especially with a script written as cell renderer) how a cell will look like, it is not possible to use the ClassNameGenerator.

So question is, how can I format the cell/row background programmatically, not using any CSS? I can provide custom component as cell value. So it's fine to render a label with icon, or just icon, or a checkbox, however coloring this rendered component is not enough, since this is smaller than the cell itself, making it look really ugly. I need to access the root element of the cell, and color it using getStyle().set("background", "xxxx"). How to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a TemplateRenderer.

For example:

```
Grid<Person> grid = new Grid<>();
grid.setItems(people);

grid.addColumn(TemplateRenderer
       .<Person>of("<b>[[item.name]]</b>")
       .withProperty("name", Person::getName)
).setHeader("Name");
```

Checkout this tutorial for more information: https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/components/tutorial-flow-grid

Comment: Yeah, I'm already using this to render image, image+text, checkbox (for bool columns), etc. But from this, you cannot set the background of the cell. All you can do is to format the text and provide custom component (like a Div with any content inside). However if you set the background of this component what you render in the TemplateRenderer, will not color the entire cell, just the component itself.
Basically I want to color the cell background (or row background) based on different criteria, which is only available during runtime, when the cells are rendered. It cannot be predefined.

Comment: That's not possible. The only thing that you can do is to set padding of the cell to 0 and then style the content

Comment: thanks for the idea, yeah, I had to use CSS to massively "de-decorate" the grid cells, so my DIV rendered into the cell will fit 100% into the grid cell, now I'm able to color the rows and render whatever I want into the cells. So in case someone wants to achieve this, has to remove all padding/margin/decoration from the grid cells, and render a custom Div-like component, and set the padding/margin/decoration on the div and also it's then possible to set the background color. Then you have only mess with the row selection highlighting... :)

Comment: Yes this will be a problem indeed :-)

Comment: Well, if the click/select is handled on client side, it messes up the background of the rendered cells. If you click a row, it is selected, but if you click on an other row, the previously selected row returns to the default color (like white). I solved it to add a clickListener to the grid, and explicitly select the clicked row on server side, this triggers "re-rendering" of the rows, and so the coloring remains perfect. It's kinda hack, and also not the best solution, but I could come up with this one. Now I have problems with the treegird toggle (since I use the treegrid not the grid).

Answer (score 0):

OK, finally I solved. I use a template renderer with a proper template structure. I modified the cell style in a way, that my renderer DIV fills the entire cell (removed any padding/margin from the original cells)

```
<dom-module id="grid-style" theme-for="vaadin-grid">
  <template>
    <style>
    [part~='cell'] ::slotted(vaadin-grid-cell-content) {
        padding: 0px;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        --cellopa: 255;
      }

      [part~='cell'][aria-selected~="true"] ::slotted(vaadin-grid-cell-content) {
              --cellopa: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

I also added some simple CSS declarations to one of the main CSS:

```
    vaadin-grid-tree-toggle flow-component-renderer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

vaadin-grid-cell-content flow-component-renderer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

This way the rendered DIV fills the whole cell and I can color it's background.

Now the problem comes with the selection, since the selection is not visible any more. For this you find the --cellopa variable set to 255 normally and set to 0 for selected cells.

Now when I define a background-color on the div, I use rgba and I set the alpha to the var(--cellopa) variable, like this for example rgba(255, 0, 0, var(--cellopa))

Now when the row is not selected, the cellopa is 255, so the background is visible, when I select the row the cellopa is set to 0, so the background of the DIV gets transparent, and the row selection color on the row is visible. This is super fast, and changing the selection does not cause any glitch, and also the previous coloring state is restored properly.

I also managed to get around with the treegrid and managed to color even the hierarchy column fully using a special template for the hierarchy column with some padding taking the level into account.